# Testing a SED command for replacing text, it gives no error, but it isn't working as intended

Tags: unix, sed, sh

I'm trying to search in all files a text, and replace it with the word EXAMPLE. I do the following:

```
for f in /home/testu/zz*; do
        sed -i "s/&VAR1\s*=\s*'?[1]{4}'?/EXAMPLE/g" "$f"
done
```

It gives no error, the files seems to be "updated" in the filesystem, but they wont get  changed. If I test that regexp with the grep command it works fine, so something must be wrong with SED, could it be SED version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried that before, and it didn't work :(

Comment: Are you aware that `[1]{4}` matches `1111`? Is that your intention?

Comment: Yes, its intentional that [1]{4}.

Comment: Ah, use `sed -i "s/&VAR1\s*=\s*'\?1\{4\}'\?/EXAMPLE/g"` or `sed -i "s/&VAR1[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*'\?1\{4\}'\?/EXAMPLE/g"`

Comment: Somethings is wrong with that last one. Script never ends and does nothing :P

Comment: Well, it [works](https://ideone.com/4XGQrR) in GNU sed. Another variation: `sed -i "s/&VAR1[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*'\{0,\}1\{4\}'\{0,\}/EXAMPLE/g"`, or `sed -i -E "s/&VAR1[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*'?1{4}'?/EXAMPLE/g"`

Comment: sed -i "s/&VAR1\s*=\s*'*1111/EXAMPLE/g" "$f" works, but sed -i "s/&VAR1\s*=\s*'*[1]{4}/EXAMPLE/g" "$f" not. Cant use [] and {}?

Comment: Did you see my examples? If you use `sed -i '...'` you must use `1\{4,\}` and if you use `sed -i -E '...'`, you may use `1{4}`. You do not need `[...]` around 1 char, remove them.

Comment: So, does anything work from the https://ideone.com/4XGQrR? What is your `sed --version`? Mine says `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: Mine is: GNU sed versión 4.1.5

Comment: sed -i "s/&VAR1[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*'\{0,\}1\{4\}'\{0,\}/EXAMPLE/g" says sed: no input files and i cant used -E, it says invalid option.

Comment: :) Provide the input file,add `"$f"`  at the end - I only added the sed command, you must put it into your script at the right place, not replace the whole script.

Comment: zz1 has &VAR1 = 1111. zz2 has &VAR1     =     '1111' and zz3 has &VAR1  =  1111; The regexp works until here: sed -i "s/&VAR1\s*=\s*'*/EXAMPLE/g" "$f"

Comment: If it behaves as Mac sed, try `sed -i '' "s/.../..../" "$f"`. Try escaping `&` char, too.

Comment: It fails: sed: cant read s/&VAR1\s*=\s*'*1{4}'*\;/EXAMPLE/g: File or directory dont exist

Answer (score 1):

Your current `sed` command parses the regular expression as a POSIX BRE compliant pattern.

In BRE POSIX, `?` matches a literal `?` char, and `{` / `}` also match literal `{` / `}` chars. To make a range quantifier in a BRE POSIX pattern, you need to escape `{...}`, `\{min,max\}`.

The `[1]` is equal to `1`, so the brackets are quite redundant here.

To fix your pattern, you may replace `?` with `\{0,1\}` (0 or 1 occurrences) and `{4}` with `\{4\}`:

```
sed -i "s/&VAR1\s*=\s*'\{0,1\}1\{4\}'\{0,1\}/EXAMPLE/g" "$f"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew tips, we got the solution (SSED GNU 4.1.5). The resulting regexp works with grep and sed. The code was a mix of solutions at the end.

```
sed -i "s/&VAR1\s*=\s*'\{0,\}1\{4\}'\{0,\};\{0,\}/EXAMPLE/g" "$f"
```

A few things:

Things like [[:blank:]] caused error of input file.

My sed version didnt support -E, so the {} had to be escaped, didn't know that :)

Thanks again Wiktor!

Comment: To thank me, please consider accepting/upvoting my answer